# MSFT0001 touchpad on a Lenovo Idepad Flex 5 14ARE05 not working under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS nor 22.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, lenovo, 22.04

My problem is that I have install a fresh Ubuntu on my Lenovo laptop. I have used Windows for a year, and wanted to try something new. The problem is that, in 99% of the time my touchpad is not working. Everything else works, touchscreen, keyboard lighting, the pen which came with the laptop. I have tried to use an older kernel with some modifications, as others suggested, but no luck so far.
An interesting thing is, when I leave the laptop closed for several minutes and come back to it and open it, the touchpad comes back to life and works just fine until I restart the computer.
Another interesting thing is, when the touchpad is not working, even the

> sudo xinput -list

command doesn't even lists it.
Any ideas how can I solve the issue?

Comment: Start by updating UEFI and disabling Fast Boot.

Comment: Tried to update UFEI, even tried to diasble it, but no luck. About the Fast boot, I can't seem to find any options to do that in the bios menu.

Comment: Your have UEFI, not BIOS, like all consumer grade computers since more than a decade ago. Yes, many people who should know better and many vendors still call it "BIOS" or "UEFI BIOS" (which is the same as saying "motor driven horseless horse carriage"). And no, UEFI is a firmware and can't be disabled. Some UEFIs however still allow Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode and that's what you may be referring to with "tried to disable it" (BTW this is the dumbest move you can do and any OS properly installed in UEFI mode will NOT boot with "legacy only" enabled).

Comment: Thanks, for your answer.

Comment: The motherboard's firmware, be it the new UEFI or the old BIOS, is the resident software responsible for the initial boot process -and- **hardware initialization**. That's why this is likely an UEFI issue, not OS, hence the suggestion to update it because even brand new computers need such updates. You should find updates, if any, at Lenovo's website along with instructions. A new version may or may not solve your issue but it's the first step to try.

Comment: PS - NOT an answer, just a comment.

Comment: The only thing that doesn't make any sense to me, is why i.e. Windows's bootloader can handle it, and works perfectly on it, but Ubuntu doesn't. I will still try to update my UEFI, thanks for that advice.

Comment: That happens because the hardware and drivers were developed for Windows and Windows only. Windows itself or the manufacturer's drivers often can compensate for hardware initialization issues of an half-baked firmware. If you want to install Linux, by itself or dual-booting, then you need to be aware of this potential pitfalls and how to troubleshoot them.